gopro firmware hack strategy to find and change an "enum"
I am looking for a way to find and change an option of photo timelapse (0.5s, 1s, 2s, etc) directly on a gopro session 5  firmware (https://gopro.com/en/us/update), which is targeting a Ambarella SoC.

Since the binary is very big, I was wondering about a stragegy to find the possible values of timelapse option and change them (say to {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, ...}).

I suspect a change may trigger a shift of all the rest of the binary. How to prevent such a mess ?


